# JQuery number generating returning incorrect length

Tags: jquery, random, numbers

For example:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 10000);
```

Would return numbers from 10000 to 99999. (Please correct me if I am wrong)
However I get a numbers like 103783 etc. sometimes.
Why is this happening?

Comment: The returned integers span the range of `10000` to `10000+99998 = 109998`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 99999 to 90000 and be careful with brackets.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363927/1845408):

```
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
```

so

```
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(99999-10000+1)+10000);
```